# pandas group by week

Tags: pandas, group-by, grouping

I have the following `test` dataframe:

```
       date                 user  answer  
0      2018-08-19 19:08:19  pga   yes   
1      2018-08-19 19:09:27  pga   no   
2      2018-08-19 19:10:45  lry   no   
3      2018-09-07 19:12:31  lry   yes
4      2018-09-19 19:13:07  pga   yes   
5      2018-10-22 19:13:20  lry   no
```

I am using the following code to group by week:

```
test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))
```

I'm getting an error that Grouper is only valid with [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), however I'm unfamiliar on how to structure this in order to group by week.

Comment: Specify the key: `test.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='W'))`. Or set `date` to the index: `test.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you have `date` column as a string.

In order to use it in a `Grouper` with a frequency, start from converting this column to `DateTime`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then, as `date` column is an "ordinary" data column (not the index), use `key='date'` parameter and a frequency.

To sum up, below you have a working example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [['2018-08-19 19:08:19', 'pga', 'yes'],
     ['2018-08-19 19:09:27', 'pga', 'no'],
     ['2018-08-19 19:10:45', 'lry', 'no'],
     ['2018-09-07 19:12:31', 'lry', 'yes'],
     ['2018-09-19 19:13:07', 'pga', 'yes'],
     ['2018-10-22 19:13:20', 'lry', 'no']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['date', 'user', 'answer'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
gr = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='W'))
for name, group in gr:
    print(' ', name)
    if len(group) > 0:
        print(group)
```

Note that the group key (`name`) is the **ending** date of a week, so dates from group members are **earlier or equal** to the date printed above.

You can change it passing `label='left'` parameter to `Grouper`.

Comment: I think I'm almost there, thanks. I came across this error: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'normalize'. This is the first time I've seen an error like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose, your source (text) data is corrupted.
Maybe it contains a row with impropper date format.
Try to call datetime with *errors='coerce'* param and then
look at the resulting DataFrame whether it contains any *NaT* value.
If you find such a case, look at the corresponding row of the
source data, especially at the date field.
Maybe there is something to correct.
Another approach: Try my script on **smaller parts** of your source data,
(e.g. first half, then second half, in case of error in some part,
try again, further dividing the suspected part into smaller chunks).